# Jest complains Cannot find module when using Yarn Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, yarnpkg

So I have a components library that a repo uses to import its UI components. When I `yarn link` the library, every change works with the repo except for unit-testing with `jest`

For some reason `jest` is not "smart enough" to detect package being `yarn linked` and therefore the tests fails.

The output of the errors is `Cannot find module '....' from '...'`

A workaround is doing a pre-release publish of the `components library` but that is **NOT** the solution and doesn't tackle the problem itself. I work at a company so "hacky" solutions will not be accepted.

Did anyone came across this problem and have a way to solve this?